# Access the filename parameter from shiny::downloadHandler?

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to take the user-provided filename from an R Shiny downloadHandler and use it to parameterize other functions in my app.

Here's the code for the download button:

```
output$dwn_all <- shiny::renderUI({
  shiny::req(tadat$raw)
  shiny::downloadButton(ns("download_all"),
                        "Download Working Dataset (.xlsx)",
                        style = "color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"
  )
})

output$download_all <- shiny::downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste("downloaded_data", params$job_id, ".xlsx", sep = "")
  },
  content = function(file) {
    writexl::write_xlsx(params$results, path = file)
  }
)
```

where `params` is a reactive object I'm using to hold quasi-global variables. I'd like to take the path provided by the user and add it to `params` so that I can create and save metadata files in the same location where the user saves the Excel file.

Comment: The value `paste("downloaded_data", params$job_id, ".xlsx", sep = "")` is exactly what `filename` would be. You can add that to your `params` if you like. But that's not a value the user provides. Unless you create your own input for the user, the browser will not give you the users full file path for security reasons. The `filename` function is just to get a value to suggest to the browser what to name the file during download. I'm not sure I understand where you are trying to use this value.

Comment: You're right, I guess it's not `filename` I want as much as what the user provides. It sounds like this isn't accessible.

Comment: I think they mean that if the user edits the suggested filename, they want the final one (with or without path is not clear).  I agree it seems an odd requirement.

Comment: You're right, I guess it's not `filename` I want as much as what the user provides (with the full path). It sounds like this isn't accessible.


What I was hoping to do was to automatically save a metadata file alongside the Excel file when a user downloads their data.

Comment: Given that shiny is just like any other webserver, you absolutely cannot write to arbitrary locations on a users computer via the browser. That would be a big security problem. You will not have the ability to write additional metadata files to the same download folder. You would have to initiate another download or something. Modern browsers have more advanced javascript APIs where you can grant special permissions for local file access, but `downloadHandler` does not use that.